# Query criteria: from public variable or from form

Tags: forms, ms-access

After a few hours searching, I couldn't find any solution to this little problem I'm having.

I have a query that retrieves one of its criteria from a form. I have referenced correctly the value on the form from the query, and it works, but what I wanted to do is a bit more complicated: when the form is closed, I want to launch the query with a "default value".

I tried to do it in 2 different ways:
a) Defining an "IIf" at the query criteria: I would need a function that checks if the form from which I retrieve the values is open.
b) Defining public variables with a default value, which would be changed from the form: I don't know where/when to initialize the value of the variable.

Does anyone have a better idea on how to do this?

TL;DR: Query gets criteria from form when it's open. If form is closed, query uses default value. HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a VBA function in a module to do this :

```
Function MyCriterion() As Long

  MyCriterion = 1234                           '   default value

  If CurrentProject.AllForms("MyForm").IsLoaded Then

      MyCriterion = Forms("MyForm").MyControl.Value

  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! it works perfectly! The "On Error Resume Next" was exactly what I was misssing.

Comment: One more question, if you could help me: I want "MyCriterion" to be a wildcard as default value, but when I put

`MyCriterion = "*"`

the query doesn't recognize it as a wildcard. Do you have any suggestion on how to pass a wildcard to the query from VBA? Thanks!

Comment: I defined MyCriterion as returning `Long`. If you want to use `*` as default, you should define it as returning `String` and use `LIKE MyCriterion`

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to put the "LIKE" on the query's criteria.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is almost never a good idea, and should only be used as a last resort, in this case you have a very easy check as to whether or not a form is loaded `CurrentProject.AllForms("MyForm").IsLoaded`

Comment: @Remou, in this case you rightly point out there is a test one can use. In the general case, VBA has a lot of *last resort* situations where one cannot test for the existence of a member of an object without generating an exception. For me, *almost never* is too strong.

Comment: Over many years, I have almost never had to use On Error Resume Next in a live file. In fact, I think never might be more likely. Missing properties should be added in developement, I reckon, other than that, there are not that many "last resorts" that spring to mind.